# How Do Jedi/Sith Stay In Shape?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, sith

Do Jedi/Sith use gyms or observe exercise regimens? **Are there any examples in-universe (Legends or Canon) of common exercise being performed by either sect/group?**

Yes we know they tend to run and be active during battles, obviously, but what about downtime? A Jedi/Sith are bound to have a lot of that between incidents of combat/action out in the field. In that life, one would need to stay in shape somehow, as it would demand it.

Comment: Does Yoda's training of Luke on Dagobah count?  It was pretty clear he was doing some pretty intense physical training as well as Force exercises.

Comment: @DavidW - I always saw that as Yoda forcing Luke to call upon the force to help him with the physical exertion, rather than a purposeful workout.

Comment: I'd imagine that daily lightsaber training is pretty vigorous

Comment: @DavidW - Rey was also subjected to the same regimen, jogging, jumping, etc

Comment: There's at least [one overweight Jedi in canon](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ram_Jomaram). It's noted in [his official Bio](https://www.starwars.com/databank/ram-jomaram) that his lightsaber skills are crap.